# the month doesnt appear using for loop

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, for-loop

i am trying to write a loop to allows people to choose month. But the month doesnt appear.

heres my code which isnt working:

**View**

```
<div>
    <?php echo form_open("announcement/announcement_result");?>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('q', $q, set_value('q'), 'id="q"'); ?>
    <?php echo form_submit('search', 'SEARCH'); ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function announcement_list() 
{

  $q = '';
  $data['q'] = $q;

  $this->data['q'] = array(
    '' => 'Month',
    );
    for($m = 1;$m <= 12; $m++)
    { 
              $month =  date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m)); 
              $this->data['q'][$month] = $month;
    }
   $data['results'] = $this->news_model->get_announcement_list($config['per_page'], $page);
}
```

Comment: `heres my code which isnt working`, what is not working??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju the dropdown doesnt show month,, it is just blank

Comment: did u checked the answer??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju yes sir,, thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning values to `$this->data` and trying to access in `$q`.

That's the problem.

Change like this in controller

```
$q = '';
$data['q'] = $q;

$data['q'] = array(
    '' => 'Month',
);
for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) {
    $month = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m));
    $data['q'][$month] = $month;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**Controller**

```
function announcement_list() 
{

      $q[]='';
      for($m = 1;$m <= 12; $m++)
      { 
        $month =  date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m)); 
        $q[] = $month;
      }
       $data['q']=$q;
       $data['results'] = $this->news_model->get_announcement_list($config['per_page'], $page);
}
```